# ERC20 Token sends 0 tokens in return

Tags: solidity

I have build a token and a crowdsale contract based on ethereum tutorials.
Whenever I send 1 Ether to the Crowdsale contract, which I linked with the Token contract, it sends back 0 tokens.
[image]
[image]
Crowdsale.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import 'browser/SafeMath.sol';
import 'browser/ERC20.sol';

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    using SafeMath for uint;
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public deadline;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;
    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    constructor (
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,
        uint durationInMinutes,
        uint etherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable public {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
       emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() public afterDeadline {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }
        crowdsaleClosed = true;
    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() public afterDeadline {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                   emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
               emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Token.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import 'browser/SafeMath.sol';
import 'browser/ERC20.sol';
import 'browser/Approve.sol';
import 'browser/Owner.sol';

contract FixedSupplyToken is ERC20Interface, Owned {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor(string _symbol, string _name, uint8 _decimals, uint256 __totalSupply) public {
        symbol = _symbol;
        name = _name;
        decimals = _decimals;
        _totalSupply = __totalSupply;
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply * 10**uint(decimals);
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply.sub(balances[address(0)]);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account `tokenOwner`
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to `to` account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer `tokens` from the `from` account to the `to` account
    // 
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the `from` account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account. The `spender` contract function
    // `receiveApproval(...)` is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Don't accept ETH
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function () public payable {
        revert();
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be actually using your `FixedSupplyToken` from your second code block. In the payable function of `Crowdsale`, you're merely calling an empty method of an interface, `transfer`, that is.

Try to import your token contract.

Comment: @PaulRBerg Could you explain what you mean? It looks to me like the fallback function in `Crowdsale` has the line `tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);`. `tokenReward` is a state variable which is assigned an address in the constructor.

Comment: Most likely the issue is that `amount / price < 1`. For example, it looks from the screenshot (though counting 0s in a screenshot is error prone) that you sent 0.5 ether. If `etherCostOfEachToken` is 1, then `price` is 1 ether, and 0.5 ether / 1 ether is 0. (Solidity uses only integer math.) If you share a link to the transaction on Etherscan, it would be possible to quickly determine the actual values.

Comment: @smarx you're right, I didn't catch that part in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small amount of sleuthing uncovered the actual transaction on Ropsten: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x2821e222ed6983c8df0ab338016f81ec539b84f76314890dc8737e8d0add0b70.

That confirms my hypothesis in the comments above. 0.5 ether was transferred to contract `0xb979e6585e521bc7928e061bf6176a447f378f4b`, and assuming the above code is the right code for that contract, the `price` should be found at storage slot 4:

```
$ http post https://ropsten.infura.io jsonrpc=1.0 method=eth_getStorageAt params:='["0xb979e6585e521bc7928e061bf6176a447f378f4b", "0x04", "latest"]' id:=1 | jq -r .result
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000
```

0xde0b6b3a7640000 == 1000000000000000000, which is 1 ether. The fallback function for the crowdsale contract divides the incoming amount by the price, and 0.5 ether / 1 ether == 0. So 0 token units are transferred.

Comment: Yes I used 0.5 ether. Shouldn't it give me a fraction of the token since I used decimals? And how can I fix it? I want for 0.5 ether to reward a buyer with more tokens. Oh, btw I used etherPriceOfEachToken=1ether. If I buy for 1 ether or more metamask sends error. I also used etherpriceofeachtoken=5 and bought for 1 ether and the result was still 0

Comment: You're the one setting the price, so you can make this do whatever you want. Assuming the token has 18 decimal places (just like ether), you probably just want to drop the `* 1 ether` and just  do `price = etherCostOfEachToken`.

Comment: For the error you get when you try to use more ether (probably something about an always failing transaction?), my guess is that you never transferred any tokens to the Crowdsale contract, so it has no tokens to transfer out.

Comment: I'm trying again keeping in mind your advices. But whenever I change the * 1 ether either with static variable like a number or divide it by 2 for example, metamask throws error

Comment: _When_ does MetaMask give you an error, and _what_ error is it? Again, I'm assuming the problem is that you never transferred any tokens to the Crowdsale contract. So any time you try to get more than 0 tokens out of it, it should revert the transaction.

Comment: Yeeeey. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6f6b6b4c8f089554e076f9e9caaffbfa0100308992d26d6fcf012b27f22bd484

Comment: I divided the price by 2 and sent some tokens to the crowdsale and worked. but for some reasons it gave me 0.000000000000000002 . This math is killin me.

Comment: This is what i did: beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether / 2;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward); Shouldn't it reward me with 2 tokens since I bought for 1 ether ?

Comment: It's going to reward you with 2 units of the token. If the token has 18 decimal places, then that's 0.00...2 (17 zeros). As I said, you probably want to drop the `* 1 ether`.

Comment: Well doing so ; price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether / 2; shouldn't fix it? Because now metamask throws error

Comment: Oh, drop it as in dont use it no more :D got it working. Thanks @smarx